# Default values for out parameters

Tags: c#, out

Take this function:

```
public void GetOutlineDateAndMediaClassification(string talksdatabase, int talknumber, out DateTime date, out bool hasMedia)
{
    date = new DateTime(1900, 1, 1);
    hasMedia = false;

    try
    {
        XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(talksdatabase);
        var ptInfo = doc
                        .Descendants("PublicTalk")
                        .Where(p => p.Attribute("Number").Value == talknumber.ToString()).First();

        if (ptInfo != null)
        {
            date = DateTime.Parse(ptInfo.Attribute("IssueDate").Value).Date;
            hasMedia = Convert.ToBoolean(ptInfo.Attribute("Media").Value);
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        SimpleLog.Log(ex);
    }
}
```

It has two `out` parameters. I wanted the **default** values to be assigned **inside** the `try` block. But the system flags they are not initialized.

[image]

So I moved them to the top of the function. But the `DateTime` constructor might through an exception, which is why I wanted to declare it in the `try` block.

What's the right way to deal with this conundrum?

Comment: *"But the system flags they are not initialized."* - which system? third party code analyzer?

Comment: on a hindsight should the code analyzer still complains, you might better to output a class instance, `Tuple`, or a `dynamic` for the sake of flexibility (bad advice though).

Comment: Just assign `default` and then again later

Comment: If you're actually using `new DateTime(1900, 1, 1);` as the default, as your code shows, then I can't think of any possible way that would throw an exception unless the whole system is borked, in which case you have bigger problems on your hands.

Comment: @DanielA.White That is a simple solution and works well.

Comment: _"I want to assign default values inside the try-catch"_ Why? Your updated question doesn't clarify that. Given the default values you're using, I can't see any benefit from assigning them inside the try-catch.

Comment: @JLRishe If I declare with `new` BEFORE the `try` statement then my code block misses the exception (if it fails) and I want to handle it there and then, not bubble up the call stack.

Comment: As I've already said, `date = new DateTime(1900, 1, 1);` is never going to throw an exception. There is nothing to catch.

Comment: If `XDocument.Load(talksdatabase);` throws exception then out parameters will be unassigned, that's why the compiler complains.

Comment: @JLRishe  @ dmitry-bychenko Understood.

Comment: @AndrewTruckle Which value to `date` and `hasMedia` should be assigned when any exception inside the `try` block is thrown before your default values for `date` and `hasMedia` is assigned (like when `XDocument.Load()` is throwing an exception)?

Comment: @Progman  I see that the exception handler should t the values too for the case describe.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the out parameters are set inside the `try`-block, you could have a situation where your code throws before you set the out parameters. In that case the code will continue executing in the catch block. This would be fine if you set them there as well, or throw an Exception. But since you don't, you will return from the function without having set the out parameters. That is not allowed.
Please see the comments I have added to your code for more clarity:

```cs
public void GetOutlineDateAndMediaClassification(string talksdatabase, int talknumber, out DateTime date, out bool hasMedia)
{
    try
    {
        XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(talksdatabase); // (1) Assume Document.Load(talksdatabase) throws an exception. Note that you have not set date or hasMedia yet.
        var ptInfo = doc
                        .Descendants("PublicTalk")
                        .Where(p => p.Attribute("Number").Value == talknumber.ToString()).First();

        date = new DateTime(1900, 1, 1);
        hasMedia = false;

        if (ptInfo != null)
        {
            date = DateTime.Parse(ptInfo.Attribute("IssueDate").Value).Date;
            hasMedia = Convert.ToBoolean(ptInfo.Attribute("Media").Value);
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        // (2) Your code will continue here after (1) without executing the rest of the try-block. date and hasMedia still have not been set. 
        SimpleLog.Log(ex);
    }

    // (3) There is no more code to execute but date and hasMedia are not set. This is invalid.
}
```